# Capturing an after save event

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any way I can execute some JavaScript code after the Dynamics CRM entity form is saved. The available OnSave event fires before the form is saved actually.

What I want to do is: to get the newly created record's id and set it on the lookup field on the opener window. For this I have:

- Created a button (web resource) on a custom form to open another CRM entity record in new mode
- When user will save the new record, I want to get the record ID and set it over the lookup field on the opener window (window.opener).

*NOTE: I am not using the built-in lookup here because I have to pass some data from the opener window to over the new record.*

Comment: http://inogic.com/blog/2014/04/opening-a-pre-populated-child-record-form-in-dynamics-crm/ but you'll have to leverage mappings to pass data for this approach to work

Comment: I believe mapping and as well as the link you provided only explains about opening a pre-populated form. Where I was stuck with is how to get back the ID of a newly created entity record (e.g. Lead) and populate the opener window's lookup.

Comment: Also, I am not initiating the new lead record from the grid page. I have a custom activity form from where I want to add a new lead record, pass some data in the lead page, associate the activity back to the new lead.

Comment: Saving the form will change the [Form Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#BKMK_getFormType) from Create to Update. You could try adding the javascript to the onLoad event instead, check `Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType` and write back to window.opener when the Form Type is set to Update.

Comment: I am going to give it a try but what if user has clicked "Save and Close"? Still in this case I will get the OnLoad event for 'Update'?

Comment: @jim0thy I again needed to capture the after save :) ... I found that in CRM Online the page load event doesn't get fired on record save. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could attach your JavaScript function onto the OnChange event of the Modified date field.

This field will update after the form is saved.

Comment: OK. Sorry for replyin too late. Will this work even if user hits "Save and Close"?

Comment: No it will not  trigger it with Save and Close